# Failed at the electron@1.8.2 postinstall script

Tags: npm, electron

I was trying to install electron into my project, but it is giving an error. I also tried to do this with unsafe-perm, but still giving the same error.

```
npm install electron --save-dev --save-exact

> electron@1.8.2 postinstall E:\PrgLang\Electron\crypto-app\node_modules\electron
> node install.js

Downloading electron-v1.8.2-win32-x64.zip
[============================================>] 100.0% of 55.21 MB (1.51 MB/s)
E:\PrgLang\Electron\crypto-app\node_modules\electron\install.js:47
throw err
^

Error: Could not parse checksum file at line 1:
at new ChecksumParseError (E:\PrgLang\Electron\crypto-app\node_modules\sumchecker\build.js:71:127)
at E:\PrgLang\Electron\crypto-app\node_modules\sumchecker\build.js:130:20
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at E:\PrgLang\Electron\crypto-app\node_modules\sumchecker\build.js:125:38
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at ChecksumValidator.parseChecksumFile (E:\PrgLang\Electron\crypto-app\node_modules\sumchecker\build.js:121:14)
at <anonymous>
npm WARN crypto-app@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN crypto-app@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@1.8.2 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.8.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Harshit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-11T03_33_52_399Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 8):

Can you please try(after removing node_modules)

`sudo npm install electron --save-dev --save-exact --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

I was running into the same error and this is what worked for me.

Comment: Working for me!! Good one.

Comment: I think `--unsafe-perm=true` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8228) it could potentially be solved with one of the following actions:

- remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again
- rename the SHASUM file in your user home directory's .electron folder

Comment: Is a new SHASUM file created within your local `.electron` folder?

Comment: Any luck solving this. I'm having the same exact issue on Linux server. Everything worked perfectly on my local WAMP server of course...

Answer (score 1):

The postinstall script of Electron is downloading a binary from a non-npm domain (possibly github.com), for which the proxy may not be configured.