# Is there a way to pass these errors to launch my electron app?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I have made an electron app but now I'm trying to launch it but it doesn't work the logs I get are

```
112 verbose node v14.15.0
113 verbose npm  v6.14.8
114 error code ELIFECYCLE
115 error errno 1
116 error electron@6.0.11 postinstall: `node install.js`
116 error Exit status 1
117 error Failed at the electron@6.0.11 postinstall script.
117 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
118 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package,json

```
{
  "name": "store_electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "trying ",
  "main": ".main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"electron",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": " electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.11",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

And the main.js

```
const {app, dialog,BrowserWindow} = require('electron') 
const fs=require('fs')
const url = require('url') 
const path = require('path')  
let win  

function createWindow() { 
   win = new BrowserWindow( 
      {width: 800, height: 600,
         webPreferences: {nodeIntegration:true}
      }
    ) ;
   win.loadURL(url.format ({ 
      pathname: path.join(__dirname,'index.html'), 
      protocol: 'file:', 
      slashes: true 
   })) ;
console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] }))

}  






app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

I have followed the quick start guide to understand and make changes but it remains in this state .I would like someone help me

Comment: Please add your `package.json` file content and `install.js` content.

Comment: I think I added it now

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728091/failed-at-the-electron1-8-2-postinstall-script